# Comparing the enum constants in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have an enum, `Constants`:

```
enum Constants {
    ONE,TWO,THREE;
}
```

How can I compare the enum Constants in Thymeleaf.

Thanks.

Comment: how are you comparing it? simply use `==` to compare enum.

Answer (score 98):

To compare with an enum constant, use the following code:

```
th:if="${day == T(my.package.MyEnum).MONDAY}"
```

Comment: @TimBüthe This is operator to access a class level (static) field or method, the part of SpEL (Spring Expression Language). See Types section (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-types) for more information.

Comment: This will cause you problems when you refactor the package of the enum.

Comment: please check https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/816, there is a breaking change in how static constants are handled in later versions of Thymeleaf for certain cases - the workaround is given in the answer by Adam Wise

Answer (score 45):

One more way:

```
th:if="${constant.name() == 'ONE'}"
```

It's shorter but makes compare with string representation, can cause problem while refactoring.

Comment: @tibi Even if your IDE not support templates refactoring (IntelliJ Idea, I think, support), if you will use Nick's answer, you will got check for enum value during page rendering. In this case - not, this is price for shorter form.

Comment: I'd say this is the best answer here.

Comment: .name() saved my day bcz in my case it was comparing enum to string and it was always false, when I added .name() it worked

Comment: Side note: This solution can also be used if `constant` is declared in a `th:each` in the same element. However, extracting the `name()` call to a `th:with` within the same element breaks it. Currently not sure what the issue is - using a `th:each` variable in a `th:with`, using that `th:with` in a conditional, or the combination of both.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is using the method name() of the enum in a switch. An example would be:

```
  <th:block th:switch="${imageType.name()}>
     <span th:case="'ONE'"></span>
     <span th:case="'TWO'"></span>
     <span th:case="'THREE'"></span>
  </th:block>
```

It is similar to a Java Switch swith ENUM instead of other answers like `${day == T(my.package.MyEnum).MONDAY}` or `${#strings.toString(someObject.constantEnumString) == 'ONE'}` which looks very strange.

Answer (score 7):

```
th:if="${#strings.toString(someObject.constantEnumString) == 'ONE'}">
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
th:if="${ day.toString() == 'MONDAY'}"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 3):

As other answers have mentioned, the 'T()' method allows access to members of an enum, but it requires the full package path name, which can be quite long. This is a bit cumbersome, especially if the enum needs to be referenced multiple times. Using 'th:with' allows it to be more readable and maintainable.

```
<div th:with="MyEnum=${T(my.package.MyEnum)}">
    <div th:if="${day == MyEnum.MONDAY}">
        <span>Happy Monday!</span>
    </div>
    <div th:if="${day == MyEnum.FRIDAY}">
        <span>TGIF!</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I tend to add `isXXX()` methods to my enums:

```
enum Constants {
    ONE,TWO,THREE;
    public boolean isOne() { return this == ONE; }
    public boolean isTwo() { return this == TWO; }
    public boolean isThree() { return this == THREE; }
}
```

Then, if `value` is an instance of your enum, you can use `th:if="${value.one}"`.

Comment: I would suggest that isXX() or hasXX() methods are useful if they add higher-level semantics (eg. isWeekend() for days of the week), but seem redundant if they merely identify the value. Since the value represents itself already.

Comment: @ThomasW I disagree.  It allows a much more terse, and much more _readable_ syntax in the template.  E.G., you can use the concise `th:if="${day.monday}"` instead of the horribly verbose and incredibly ugly `th:if="${day == T(my.package.MyEnum).MONDAY}"`

Comment: Hi @daiscog. I guess I understand your point of view -- if the template is a major place where the enums are used, this makes coding easier. However I feel Thymeleaf at this point is letting us down; in an ideal world, we wouldn't need to redeclare what enums are or use such an ugly syntax to compare. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasW Yes, I completely agree it would be better if Thymeleaf made checking enums easier so we didn't have to do this. 

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to convert your Enum into a string in your object you can do it like this:

```
th:if="${#strings.defaultString(someObject.myConstant, 'DEFAULT_VALUE') == 'ONE'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefere use wrapper around the enum.

```
public class ConstantsWrapper {
    public static final instance = new ConstantsWrapper();
    public Constants getONE() { return Constants.ONE }
    public Constants getTWO() { return Constants.TWO }
    public Constants getTHREE() { return Constants.THREE }
}
```

Next step is adding new instance of Wrapper into models

```
models.add("constantsWrapper", ConstantsWrapper.instance);
```

Now you have type safe access in thymeleaf template to the each value of `Constants`.

```
th:if="${value == constantsWrapper.getONE()}"
```

I know that this solutions needs to write more source code and create one instnace. 
Advantage is more type safe than call `T()` and write full qualified name directly into template. With this solution you can refactor without testing your templates.

Answer (score 0):

Example #1:

```
enum Constants {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE;
}
```

Solution:

```
th:if="${string == T(com.example.Constants).ONE}"
 
   OR

th:if="${string == T(com.example.Constants).ONE.toString()}"
```

NB: You can use `.toString()` for safety.

---

Example #2:

```
enum Constants {
    ONE("One"),
    TWO("Two"),
    THREE("Three");
}
```

Solution:

```
th:if="${string == T(com.example.Constants).ONE.toString()}"
```

NB: When your enum has Description, You have to use `.toString()`.

---

Example #3:

```
enum Constants {
    ONE("One"),
    TWO("Two"),
    THREE("Three");
}
```

Solution:

```
th:if="${'One' == T(com.example.Constants).ONE.getName()}"
```

NB: Enum description call by `.getName()`.