# Thymeleaf - Always keep the HTML element but conditionally show a value

Tags: thymeleaf

I need Thymeleaf to always include a `label` element but only conditionally show a value for it.

If `message.type` is equal to `warning` it should show the `message.text`. Otherwise, the HTML DOM should still contain the `label` element.

I've tried this but then the `label` element is missing from the HTML when the `message.type` is not equal to `warning`.

```
<label id="message" th:if="${message.type == 'warning'}" 
   th:value="${message.text}" th:text="${message.text}"></label>
```

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

```
<label id="message" th:value="${message.type=='warning' ? 
    message.text: ''}" th:text="${message.type=='warning'? 
   message.text: ''"></label>
```

If the `message.type` is warning, I would expect HTML like this:

```
<label id="message">My warning message</label>
```

Otherwise, I would like to have HTML like this:

```
<label id="message"></label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many different ways to accomplish this.  You already have one that I would expect to work. (why do you say it doesn't work?)  Also, I'm not sure why you are including `th:value` in your tags (I'm including them to match your question).

```
<label
    id="message"
    th:value="${message.type == 'warning'? message.text : ''}"
    th:text="${message.type == 'warning'? message.text : ''}"></label>
```

You could also do something like this:

```
<label th:if="${message.type == 'warning'}" id="message"  th:value="${message.text}" th:text="${message.text}"></label>
<label th:unless="${message.type == 'warning'}" id="message"></label>
```

or like this (assuming an extra span wouldn't mess up the markup you are wanting):

```
<label id="message"><span th:if="${message.type == 'warning'}" th:text="${message.text}" /></label>
```

Comment: Thanks. The ternary op works. Looks like I had a typo in my code. Also, it was not working for an enum that I was using. I was treating it the same as a string but found that I needed to handle as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28559029/1706691).