# Thymeleaf hide certain feature using if statement if the user choose certain option?

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

My selection has Document Type, Year and Month and My document type consists of Monthly Report and Annual Report

But if my document type is selected as "Annual Report", I want to hide the "Month" selection since Annual Report is based on Yearly basis. How do I put such if statement into my html?

thymeleaf html

```
            <table class="table table-borderless" cellspacing="0"
                                style="border-inline: 0;">

                                <tbody>
                                    <div th:if="${user!=null}">
                                    <tr>
        <!-- Document Type -->
                                        <td th:text="#{DocType}" />
                                        <td colspan="1">
                                            <div class="dropdown col-sm-6">
                                                <select id="documentType" class="browser-default custom-select"
                                                    th:field="*{type}">
                                                    <option
                                                        th:each="doc:${T(enums.DocumentType).values()}"
                                                        th:value="${doc}" th:text="${doc.label}"></option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr></div>
                                    <tr>
     <!-- YEAR -->
                                        <td th:text="#{Year}" />
                                        <td colspan="1">
                                            <div class="dropdown col-sm-6">
                                                <select class="browser-default custom-select" th:field="*{year}">

                                                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                                    <option th:each="year : ${years}" th:value="${year}"
                                                        th:text="${year}"></option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
     <!-- MONTH -->
                                        <td th:text="#{Month}" />
                                        <td colspan="1">
                                            <div class="dropdown col-sm-6">
                                                <select class="browser-default custom-select" th:field="*{month}">
                                                    <option value="">Please Select</option>

                                                    <option th:each="month : ${months}" th:value="${month}"
                                                        th:text="${month}"></option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

DocumentType.java

```
public enum DocumentType {

  MONTHLY("MONTHLY", "Monthly Report"),

  ANNUAL("ANNUAL", "Annual Report"),

  private String code;

  private String label;

  DocumentType(final String code, final String label) {
    this.code = code;
    this.label = label;
  }

  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  public String getLabel() {
    return label;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can accept my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 2):

To hide Month selection if the document selected is Yearly you can use the following condition on Monthly.

```
th:if="${DocumentType.getCode() != 'ANNUAL'}"
```

So the code should be something like this

```
<tr th:if="${DocumentType.getCode() != 'ANNUAL'}">
    <!-- MONTH -->
    <td th:text="#{Month}" />
    <td colspan="1">
        <div class="dropdown col-sm-6">
            <select class="browser-default custom-select" th:field="*{month}">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                <option th:each="month : ${months}" 
                        th:value="${month}"
                        th:text="${month}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

To understand how to access Enums in Thymeleaf use this link [Comparing the enum constants in thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937441/comparing-the-enum-constants-in-thymeleaf)